# Is there a way to log only the body with feign spring client?

Tags: spring-boot, feign, openfeign

Is there a way to log only the body with feign spring client? 
Using the Log.level I seem to only be able to only include the body with the full logging and in that case it is printing the headers too. 
Which I don't want to see in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The default `Logger` uses the `Log.Level` to control what is logged and works in a way that is additive.  This means that going up in level logs more information.  To customize this behavior, you will need to provide your own `Logger` implementation.  Specifically, you can extend one of the included loggers and customize the `logAndRebufferResponse` method:

```java
public class MyLogger extends JavaLogger {
     protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(String configKey,
                                        Level logLevel,
                                        Response response,
                                        long elapsedTime) {
        // only log the response data, skip the headers
     }
}
```

Next, include this logger in your Feign configuration.

```java
 API api = Feign.builder()
                 .logger(new MyLogger())
                 .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
                 .target(API.class, "https://api.example.com");
```

All instances of this Feign Client will use your logger now.